# Formatting section title text only

Tags: sectioning, titles, titlesec

There are several posts on this site about formatting section titles, but I haven't seen one yet shows me how to edit the section title without editing the default spacing. I would like to have something like

```
\section{May 10}
```

display

**Lecture 16 (May 10)**

where 16 is the section number, but keeping the old spacing.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this would work, using the `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}%
            {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}% format
            {Lecture \thesection{} (#1)}%
            {0pt}% horizontal sep
            {}% before

\begin{document}
\section{May 10}
Here is the lesson material.
\section{May 11}
Here is the new and latest lesson material.
\end{document}
```

[image]